# Is turning off a power strip enough to protect from lightning?

Tags: power

My building has no "ground" installed, so a surge protector is useless to me. I'm curious if turning off the switches on a power strip would guarantee no harm on my devices connected to it when lightning. Normally, I would unplug all the devices, but I'm just asking in case I forgot to do that.

Comment: What countries still allow unearthed mains in any building?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Will turning off the switches on a power strip guarantee no harm to my devices?

No. A lightning surge in your electric supply would just jump the switch.

Summary:

> The best, and cheapest, way to protect your stereo, television, computer, or any electronic appliance is to unplug all power, telephone (modem), and antenna connections during a thunderstorm.

---

#### Lightning Myths: Surge protectors and UPS devices provide total lightning protection.

> A common surge protector will stop voltage spikes and surges, but not the violent, catastrophic burst of current from a close lightning strike. Direct lightning current is simply too big to protect with a little electronic device inside a power strip, or even a hefty UPS unit. If your UPS or surge protector i

...

> Lightning current often peaks at 100,000 or more Amperes. With that in mind, consider if you have a lightning protection system installed, and your house is hit directly by lightning. If the protection system takes even 99.9% of the current, then your electrical wiring may take the remaining 0.1%. 0.1% of 100,000 Amperes is a 100 Amp surge through your lines- which may be enough to take out your computer.
>
> It is not uncommon for 'side flashes' to occur inside a house or building, where all or a part of the lightning will jump across an entire room to reach ground- such as from the electrical wiring system to well-grounded water pipes. If your computer is in the way, it'll be time to shop for a new one, even if you have the most expensive protection system installed.
>
> A 'side flash' often occurs when lightning branches out into several channels as it tries to bury itself deep into earth. So even if the bulk of the current is flowing to ground through the heavy cables of your protection system, there can be small 'overflow' disharges, even if the lightning hits outside of the structure. Such an event was experienced by my Grandmother, who witnessed a 6-foot long blue spark jump across the room from a wall outlet to the kitchen faucet as lightning struck nearby.

Source  [Lightning Myths: Surge protectors and UPS devices provide total lightning protection.](http://stormhighway.com/surge_protectors_ups_lightning_protection_myth.php)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Arresting the surges in lightning strikes](http://blog.schneider-electric.com/power-management-metering-monitoring-power-quality/2013/02/26/arresting-the-surges-in-lightning-strikes/)
- [How to protect your house and its contents from lightning : surge protection : IEEE guide for surge protection ...](http://lightningsafety.com/nlsi_lhm/IEEE_Guide.pdf) (PDF)

Comment: Thank you. I totally need to unplug everything when I'm not around.